# Restshap dll in windows phone apps

Tags: windows-phone, restsharp

can I use Restsharp Library for commercial purposes in windows phone apps.
I want to use this for uploading the file to server and reading the response using httpwebrequest is quite complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice, but the answer is yes.

RestSharp is licensed under the Apache v2 license. So you can do anything that the license allows.

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/LICENSE.txt